# Does teshuva exist for broken Nedarim?

Tags: nedarim-shevuot

Is there and if so, what is the teshuva process for breaking a Neder? Additionally, once the Neder is broken is it still in effect?

Comment: The teshiva process for all sins is also Confession, Regret, and Accepting not to repeat the sin in the future. Is that what you refer to?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Nachman and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 1):

Violating a Neder does not void the Neder, it is still binding and forbidden to violate in the future. The Gemara discusses a Nazir who is warned twice "do not drink", "do not drink"; and thus incurs punishment for each separate violation. The initial violation does not exempt him from future liability. (In the particular case of Nazir, breaking the vow may require him to start over, begining a new count of 30 days, as described in the Chumash.)

Comment: This answer could be improved by giving us the location in the gemera precisely and also addressing the teshuva aspect of the question